# Why is Boostrap 4.4.1 Media query not working?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, styles, media-queries

I am trying to add a responsive design to my web application using the media queries with Bootsrtap 4.4.1.

I've tried testing the media queries with the following

This is my styles.css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 575.98px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
  .buttons {
    background-color:rgba(255,180,50,0.7);
  }
}
```

Nothing changes when I test this on a small device. When I run the application I see that the style appears in chrome dev tools but it is not applied.

1. Am I missing something here? Do I need to import anything in order to use the media queries with Bootsrtap?
2. Which rule should I be using`@include` or just `@media`?

Answer (score 0):

Are these media queries on the end of your styles.css?Your styles.css file have to declared on your header after the bootstrap css file. Now something ovewrite your media queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a little mini example / then we can be sure that the problem isn't somewhere else in the project.

@include is for including mixins / when using SCSS/Sass. Also `575.98px` is a wild number. You should not be using decimal pxls. Nothing is that specific. Maybe you can explain it in further detail in the CSS Discord: https://discord.gg/pFc6XmH

```
.thing {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .thing {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/q8jz7Lt9

```css
.thing {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .thing {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .thing {
    background-color: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="thing">
  THING!
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Derek! I just fixed the resolution and tried using it on a different element and it works! For some reason it doesn't work on the <body>.

Comment: I suggest you create a CodePen or JSfiddle to show us an example.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to confirm that this is now solved. I overlooked the fact that I had a background image on the `<body>` on so this snippet was not working.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 575.98px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Once I remove the background image the style was applied. Thank you for the help and insight!